# Incorrect number of dimensions in using findDrawdowns function in R

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I've been trying to run the `findDrawdowns` function in R from the PerformanceAnalytics package and kept getting a dimension error.

My data set is called `dataset` and is a 200 rows, 1 column vector, with no NA in it. I've set up row names as dates as shown below
Here are my code lines:

```
timedate <- as.POSIXct(Date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
names(dataset) <- timedate 
maxDD <- maxDrawdown(dataset,weights=FALSE,geometric=TRUE,invert=FALSE)
findDD <- findDrawdowns(dataset,geometric=TRUE)
```

Runing `maxDrawdown` function works just fine, but the `findDrawdowns` one always leaves me with :

```
Error in R[, 1, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Is there any way I can change the data to make it fit or anything I shouldn't have missed about the function? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work when converting the vector to a matrix using `as.matrix()` on my vector. 
My new code that seems to work now is:

```
timedate <- as.POSIXct(Date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
names(dataset) <- timedate 
maxDD <- maxDrawdown(dataset,weights=FALSE,geometric=TRUE,invert=FALSE)
findDD <- findDrawdowns(as.matrix(dataset),geometric=TRUE)
```

It does not give me the error message I was getting before and seems to work properly. Though as long as the package description specify I should work with a vector, I am still very opened to get a more clean answer!